# Using "where" with SQLite in NetCore return always empty list

Tags: entity-framework, linq, sqlite, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to get a list of elements from SQLite database from local file using .NetCore 2.0 with EF and with LazyLoading enabled.

Using "where" from linq always returns no elements. But if Is after execute "ToList()" operation works.

```
var work = antDb.MapNode.ToList().Where(mp => mp.Items.Any(i => !i.Deleted)).ToList();

var notWork = antDb.MapNode.Where(mp => mp.Items.Any(i => !i.Deleted)).ToList();
```

Is it possible that I missing something or is the expected behavior?

Comment: `Deleted` is Boolean field, am I correct?

Comment: Very strange that second query is not working. I did not use SQL lite anytime. Can check with using SQL Server or SQL Server Local Db

Comment: Could you post SQL query that is generated from your (second) LINQ query? However this is odd, I have plenty of queries like this that work normally...

Comment: @TanvirArjel Yes, deleted is a boolean field. And using sql server works as expected.

Comment: Then the problem is related to SQL Lite